# После отправки формы, открывается файл php

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 

$token = ""; 
$chat_id = ""; 
$sitename = ""; 
 
$arr = array(
 
  'Заказ с сайта: ' => $sitename,
  'Имя: ' => $name,
  'Телефон: ' => $phone,
);
 
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};
 
$sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
?>
```

Как сделать чтобы после нажатия на кнопку, перебрасывало либо на другую страницу, либо чтобы оставалось на месте все

Comment: После нажатия открывается файл с таким текстом "Warning: Undefined variable $txt in /var/www/u2234687/data/www/studiomaretta.ru/telegram.php on line 18"

Comment: Ошибка и вопрос - разное. Ошибка говорит, что вам необходимо инициализировать переменную txt значением(пустой строкой). А вот вопрос относится к разметке html и скриптам javaScript, которые производят(или нет) отправку формы. Покажите разметку и скрипты

Comment: переменную $txt хотя бы для начала объявите, конкатенация применительно к несуществующей переменной ошибка (а в случае вашего перебора при 1м запуске ее еще не существует)

Answer (score 0):

В конец:

```
header("Location: ok.html");
exit( );
```

, а сверху:

```
$txt = '';
```